# Alert box not opening

Tags: javascript, debugging

I want an alert box to appear when the button is clicked but nothing happens. One thing I'm not sure is if I'm supposed to have the `var` infront of the identifier in the function signature e.g. `function popup(var message)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-ca">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Testing...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function popup(var message)
        {
            var one = 5
            var two = 3
            alert(message)
            if(one*two == 15)
            {
                alert("you were right")
            }
            else
            {
                alert("you were wrong")
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Hello, I am here.<br />
<input type="button" value="click here" onclick="popup('this is my message')" />
</body>
</html>
```

IE gives the following error details:
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 11 Jul 2012 23:12:07 UTC

Message: Object expected
Line: 25
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/UJXB9EE/Desktop/jscripttest.html

I'm not sure how to find this in FireFox.

EDIT: is there a better way to get JavaScript errors instead of clicking on the small error icon in the bottom of IE?

Comment: Semi-colons aren't required in JavaScript per se, but it is still a good idea to use them. If you don't use them the interpreter adds them in and this can lead to bugs. Something to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `var`  before a functions parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
function popup(var message)
```

to

```
function popup(message)
```

Comment: I'm new with JavaScript and really need an explanation here. I was told that `var` is meaningless and is put the first time you declare/initialize a variable for readability purposes.

Comment: I thought w3schools was unreliable?

Comment: You're right, w3schools is unreliable. http://w3fools.com/ I've blocked w3schools from my future searches!

Answer (score 0):

Im only learning myself but i think the var will make the variable local rather than global. Which is important if you want to access the variable form different functions. Hopefully some
one can confirm that for you.